# What's the maximum safe limit for fs.inotify.max_user_watches?

Tags: ubuntu, inotify

I run an Ubuntu 23.04 system with 32 GB of RAM, and about 10 nspawn containers open.

I've set `fs.inotify.max_user_watches = 120000000` but I'm STILL getting

```
Failed to allocate directory watch: Too many open files
```

What's causing this? How much more can I increase this amount of watches?

Comment: 1. You'd need to test on the machine, but that seems about 3 orders of magnitude too much. 2. Did you make the changes permanent, per https://www.suse.com/support/kb/doc/?id=000020048 ?

Comment: I've looked at that now, but it seems no matter how high I set the settings, I still get the too many open files error.

Comment: @CabbageGremlin i'm not able to set it above 1000000.  like i set it but it doesn't actually change.

Answer (score 1):

I've set `6000000` on a 64gb machine with plenty of free memory for `fs.inotify.max_user_watches`

- One possible solution here to find the upper limit is:
- `sysctl -w fs.inotify.max_user_watches=1000000`
- & keep incrementing by a million until you hit the limit of the machine (or looking at the [LXD production setup](https://documentation.ubuntu.com/lxd/to/latest/reference/server_settings/) - increment by multiples of `1048576`)

I [also found](https://watchexec.github.io/docs/inotify-limits.html) some information for calculating a maximum limit:

> The hard upper bound is controlled by how much kernel memory you are
> willing or able to dedicate for this use. One inotify watch costs 540
> bytes of kernel memory on 32-bit architectures, and 1080 bytes on
> 64-bit ones. The consuming application may have additional overhead on
> this.

- The actual limit you can set will be determined by the amount of free memory available to the kernel.